# Reading arabic text using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient, arabic

I am trying to get text from a page using webclient, but the arabic text are not displaying properly. I have tried the following codes using the following url=http://www.elnashra.com/:

test1:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream  s =   webClient.OpenRead(urlLink);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
```

test2:

```
String utf8 = webClient.DownloadString(webClient, url, Encoding.UTF8);
```

output:

> ������ ����� ����� ������ ������ - Elnashra

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - this works with me:

```
           string url = String.Format("http://www.example.com);

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);


            string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me,it return data from DownloadString as arabic text without any change in arabic text

```
    WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
    wclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string RSSData = (wclient.DownloadString(RSSURL));
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is working better that announce that it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the URL in a browser and check the response headers with the developer tools, you can see that the page is delivered in Windows-1256 encoding:

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=windows-1256
```

Could you try

```
webClient.DownloadString(webClient, url, Encoding.getEncoding(1256));
```